# ignore dev dependencies in php composer

Tags: laravel-5.3, composer-php

I have developed a composer laravel based project that I need to install on a remote production server. The problem is I have limited permission/ access so my option is to "archive" the package( using `composer archive`) and unpack on the production.

What folders do I need to archive and how can I ignore the dev dependencies of the package as well as vendor dev dependencies?

Answer (score 15):

`composer archive` is likely not to help you, because this command creates an archive of a defined version of a package.

You probably want to upload the whole working application, and not only one package. You should create a little script that will create the archive file for you, which should do:

- checkout the application from the repository in a new directory
- run `composer install --no-dev` to install all required dependencies without dev-dependencies
- optionally delete files that are not necessary on the server, like documentation, the `.git` folder, and other stuff
- create the archive file from all these files
- optionally upload that archive to the target server and unarchive there
- optionally check basic functions and switch to the new uploaded version on the server

Comment: This is where node shines with third party bundlers that automatically strip dev dependencies

Comment: Happy to learn at least one positive aspect of node. :->

Comment: Ended up setting up a script as you described, guess you can't have everything...