# ignore files but not sub folder

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.3, gitignore

I'm trying to use composer to archive my project for distribution via zip and I want to be able to ignore miscellaneous files and folders in particular I have in a .gitignore file

`/storage/`

which ignores the folder and its contents. However I have the following in the composer.json

```
"archive": {
      "exclude": ["!vendor","!storage","storage/**/*","*/**/*.json","*/**/*.lock","*/**/tests","*/**/docs","*.md","*/**/.git","gulpfile.js",".git*","!storage/*/","*/node_modules","**/*.xml","web.config","resources","!public/",".env"]
    }
```

i want to be able to include the folder and subfolders but NOT the files. However, the pattern matching doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other way to accomplish what I am doing

Comment: what about .gitattributes and export-ignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ignore dev dependencies in php composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855771/ignore-dev-dependencies-in-php-composer)

Comment: This question is already covered in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855771/ignore-dev-dependencies-in-php-composer

Comment: @Sven was hoping to use the exclude to ignore rather than "manually deleting" which proved to be a very tedious task in the end